# Upgrading to SQL Server 2017 from SQL Server 2012 time allowed

Tags: sql-server

We have a customer running a SQL 2012 database for their document management system but this needs to be upgraded, They want to upgrade to SQL Server 2017 and looking at the forums the best method is side by side.
Can I ask what sort of time should I allow for this type of upgrade - I need to inform the customer of the downtime.. Approximate size of the database is 800GB.

Any help or advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: **It depends™**. Anywhere from 1 hour to 20 hours. Test it in a test environment. There are just too much variables, to provide you with an adequate answer. Sorry. But welcome to DBA.SE nonetheless.

Comment: Is there only one database of 800Gb on the server or it's the sum of all databases together? Are you migrating to an instance on a different server or the same?

Comment: Build new SQL Server 2017, restore database and move all the related jobs and objects. Do the testing, once you are good  configure log shipping for all the databases. The cut over time is the only downtime you would need anywhere from 15 mins to 30 mins.

Answer (score 3):

Backup restore depends on a lot of different factors, the biggest ones being

1. Your network
2. Your storage

The best way to ever give a good estimation is to test it.

Setup the second server/dev env, and do the migration as a test, this will give you a very good estimation of the time it will take.
And as a second huge benefit, you'll have all scripts ready + experience for the production migration.

Comment: Fair point, changed my answer a bit. Either way testing is the only way to get somewhat of an accurate estimate.

Comment: Don't just replicate the DB for testing: have an instance of the application(s) too if possible, then you can run regression tests so you are less likely to get nasty surprises after the upgrade in production.